# Does the Ray of Sickness cause poison damage twice on a failed save?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The spell says:

> On a failed save, it is also poisoned until the end of your next turn.

Does that mean the 2d8 poison damage reapplies on the following turn, or is that just a statement meaning that the creature is poisoned for a while (but since there does not seem to be any other side effects, I do not see the point otherwise!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a failed save, Ray of Sickness inflicts the poisoned **condition** as found on page 292 of the PHB.

That's all.

The damage is only applied once.